# Multithread decoding of Video PID of Mpeg2Ts using FFMPEG

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, ffmpeg, mpeg2-ts

I'm working on an app in VC++ to display video frames of a video Pid of mpeg2ts stream using FFMPEG and need to do the same, for other mpeg2stream simultaneously by using multi thread process,my source code is:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
av_register_all();
avformat_network_init();
pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();

if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx,filepath,NULL,NULL)!=0){
    printf("Couldn't open input stream.\n");
    return -1;
}
if(avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx,NULL)<0){
    printf("Couldn't find stream information.\n");
    return -1;
}
videoindex=-1;
for(i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++) 
    if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO){
        videoindex=i;
        break;
    }
if(videoindex==-1){
    printf("Didn't find a video stream.\n");
    return -1;
}

pCodecCtx=pFormatCtx->streams[videoindex]->codec;
pCodec=avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
if(pCodec==NULL){
    printf("Codec not found.\n");
    return -1;
}
if(avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec,NULL)<0){
    printf("Could not open codec.\n");
    return -1;
}  

pFrame=av_frame_alloc();
pFrameYUV=av_frame_alloc();
out_buffer=(uint8_t *)av_malloc(avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_YUV420P, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height));
avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameYUV, out_buffer, PIX_FMT_YUV420P, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);
packet=(AVPacket *)av_malloc(sizeof(AVPacket));
//Output Info-----------------------------
printf("--------------- File Information ----------------\n");
av_dump_format(pFormatCtx,0,filepath,0);
printf("-------------------------------------------------\n");
img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, 
    pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, PIX_FMT_YUV420P, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL); 

#if OUTPUT_YUV420P 
    fp_yuv=fopen("output.yuv","wb+");  
#endif  

if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO | SDL_INIT_TIMER)) {  
    printf( "Could not initialize SDL - %s\n", SDL_GetError()); 
    return -1;
} 

screen_w = pCodecCtx->width;
screen_h = pCodecCtx->height;
//SDL 2.0 Support for multiple windows
screen = SDL_CreateWindow("Simplest ffmpeg player's Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    screen_w, screen_h, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

if(!screen) {  
    printf("SDL: could not create window - exiting:%s\n",SDL_GetError());  
    return -1;
}

sdlRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(screen, -1, 0);  
//IYUV: Y + U + V  (3 planes)
//YV12: Y + V + U  (3 planes)
sdlTexture = SDL_CreateTexture(sdlRenderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_IYUV, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING,pCodecCtx->width,pCodecCtx->height);  

sdlRect.x=0;
sdlRect.y=0;
sdlRect.w=screen_w;
sdlRect.h=screen_h;
//SDL End----------------------
BYTE buffer [4] ;
int nSize = 0 ;
int nByteCnt = 0 ;
int nPreviuosPos = 0 ;
mpgfile = fopen ("D:\\00_Projects\\Farzan II\\SampleData\\Yahsat1996V_N_PID(2101).pes", "rb");

while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, packet)>=0 /*&& nSize > 0*/)
{
    if(packet->stream_index==videoindex)
    {
        ret = avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &got_picture, packet);
        if(ret < 0)
        {
            printf("Decode Error.\n");
            return -1;
        }
        if(got_picture)
        {
            sws_scale(img_convert_ctx, (const uint8_t* const*)pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, 
                pFrameYUV->data, pFrameYUV->linesize);              
#if OUTPUT_YUV420P
            y_size=pCodecCtx->width*pCodecCtx->height;  
            fwrite(pFrameYUV->data[0],1,y_size,fp_yuv);    //Y
            fwrite(pFrameYUV->data[1],1,y_size/4,fp_yuv);  //U
            fwrite(pFrameYUV->data[2],1,y_size/4,fp_yuv);  //V
#endif
//SDL---------------------------
#if 0
            SDL_UpdateTexture( sdlTexture, NULL, pFrameYUV->data[0], pFrameYUV->linesize[0] );  
#else
              SDL_UpdateYUVTexture(sdlTexture, &sdlRect,
                pFrameYUV->data[0], pFrameYUV->linesize[0],
            pFrameYUV->data[1], pFrameYUV->linesize[1],
            pFrameYUV->data[2], pFrameYUV->linesize[2]);
#endif              
            SDL_RenderClear( sdlRenderer );  
            SDL_RenderCopy(  sdlRenderer, sdlTexture,  NULL, &sdlRect);  
            SDL_RenderPresent( sdlRenderer );  
            //SDL End-----------------------
            //Delay 40ms
            SDL_Delay(40);
        }
    }
    av_free_packet(packet);
}
//flush decoder
//FIX: Flush Frames remained in Codec
while (1) {
    ret = avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &got_picture, packet);
    if (ret < 0)
        break;
    if (!got_picture)
        break;
    sws_scale(img_convert_ctx, (const uint8_t* const*)pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, 
        pFrameYUV->data, pFrameYUV->linesize);
#if OUTPUT_YUV420P
    int y_size=pCodecCtx->width*pCodecCtx->height;  
    fwrite(pFrameYUV->data[0],1,y_size,fp_yuv);    //Y 
    fwrite(pFrameYUV->data[1],1,y_size/4,fp_yuv);  //U
    fwrite(pFrameYUV->data[2],1,y_size/4,fp_yuv);  //V
#endif
    //SDL---------------------------
    SDL_UpdateTexture( sdlTexture, &sdlRect, pFrameYUV->data[0],       pFrameYUV->linesize[0] );  
        SDL_RenderClear( sdlRenderer );  
        SDL_RenderCopy( sdlRenderer, sdlTexture,  NULL, &sdlRect);  
        SDL_RenderPresent( sdlRenderer );  
        //SDL End-----------------------
        //Delay 40ms
        SDL_Delay(40);
}

sws_freeContext(img_convert_ctx);

#if OUTPUT_YUV420P 
    fclose(fp_yuv);
#endif 

SDL_Quit();

av_frame_free(&pFrameYUV);
av_frame_free(&pFrame);
avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);
avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);

return 0;
}
```

***it works well when i call it in One thread*** but,after calling this function in *multi thread* ,the error of ***access violation*** occurred , is there anyone to guide me to solution?

Comment: This code does not match the question. There is no thread instantiation. Its not complete (missing globals) And its copied/pasted from dranger's tutorial.

Comment: thanks for your attention  @szatmary ,ofcourse this is a sample code for playing a video stream among other streams,i assume this code as a function such that it's input is a mpeg2ts stream ,now i wanna use this code with some variation of performing multi thread process, for another Transport stream simultaneously,how can i do that ?are the existed functions thread safe or i have to use critical section for all of them ??

Comment: So, what is your question? Is it what libav* functions are thread safe/reentrant? If so, what does that have to to with mpegts? Is your question how do I make this code thread safe? Well, it not even a complete, so cant answer that. But first step would be to git rid of globals. Also, the fact that the function is named main implies it will only ever be called once.

Comment: i am appreciated  @szatmary, my question is exactly how do i make this code thread safe ???

Comment: @szatmary : i am using these functions : "av_register_all()" , "avformat_network_init() ","avformat_alloc_context() " for initializing ,after that "avformat_open_input(&m_pFormatCtx,NULL,NULL,NULL)" and "avformat_find_stream_info(m_pFormatCtx,NULL)" , and for palying a specific program audio or video i make related variables by these functios,"avcodec_find_decoder" , " avcodec_open2" and finally in a loop i read frame one by one and check their content by these functions "av_read_frame " , " avcodec_decode_audio4" , "swr_convert" for audio and  "avcodec_decode_video2" ,"sws_scale" for video.

Comment: the "register" function should only be call once. Not once per thread. avcodec_find_decoder needs to be protected by a mutex. The rest are reentrant.